How to use first IP in subnet with macvlan network and Docker Compose?
I'm containerizing software that uses multiple network ports for low-level networking with connected hardware, so I use the macvlan driver in passthru mode.
I also need static IP addresses for these interfaces.
Here's a simplified docker-compose.yaml with one interface:
version: '2'

services:
  sw:
    build: ./
    networks:
      port1:
        mac_address: 00:00:00:00:00:01
        ipv4_address: 172.20.1.1
networks:
  port1:
    driver: macvlan
    driver_opts:
      parent: eth2
      macvlan_mode: passthru
    ipam:
      config:
        - subnet: "172.20.1.0/24"

With this configuration I get the error:
$ sudo docker compose up
...
Error response from daemon: Address already in use

If I change ipv4_address to 172.20.1.2 everything starts fine.
But neither the host nor the container have network interfaces that use the address 172.20.1.1:
Host:
$ ifconfig -a | grep 172.20.1.
$

Container:
# ifconfig -a
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 172.20.1.2  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 172.20.1.255
        ether 00:00:00:00:00:01  txqueuelen 0  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

Docker version: 25.0.0, build e758fe5. Pop!_OS 20.04 LTS.
Does Docker use the first subnet address for itself even in this mode?
Is it possible to override it in the configuration?
